# Draw isosceles triangle facing a certain angle based on center

Tags: c#, matlab, geometry

I'm trying to get the 2D coordinates for the 3 vertices of an isosceles triangle facing a certain angle.

I know the coordinates of the center of the triangle and have drawn a circle of radius `r` around this point, which I'm assuming should be used to determine the triangle vertices.

(I'm trying to do this in c# but the language doesn't really matter)

Comment: Why the circle? Isn't this just alinear algebra mapping? Multiply your coordinates with the rotation matrix and get the 2d coordinates from the result. Besides, if the language doesn't matter: pick mathlab ;-)

Comment: I don't know the coordinates, I only have a single 2D point for the center of the triangle and the angle that I want to face.

Comment: Aha, that change things a bit.

Comment: Do you know anything about the sizes and angles?

Comment: The only angle that I know is the one that the triangle should be pointing towards. The side sizes aren't really important and can be assigned arbitrary value for now. I assumed I would adjust these values once I know how to draw the triangle to get the look I'm going for.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the question. If you have the 3 points, it's easy to draw the triangle. To get the 3 point's you'll need to do some math. What is it exactly that you need help with? Since you have a given form, a "isosceles", you can express everything angles and distances.

Comment: Do you really mean an isosceles triangle or an equilateral one? An isosceles triangle is underdetermined with the values you have. What *center* do you have? The centroid? The center of the circumference?

Answer (score 0):

We need to add some taste of geometry here! I assume that by **the center of the triangle** you mean the center of the inscribed circle inside that triangle. Also the given angle is the angle of apex which is between 0 and 180 deg. Given the radius and the coordinates of the center of the circle and the angle of apex, the following function will do the job in **MATLAB**:

```
function output=circle2tri(radius,coordinates,apex_theta)
%% 
% radius = radius of the inscribed circle. 1*1 scalar
% coordinates = coordinates of the center of the inscribed circle. 1*n vec
% apex_theta = (self-explaining!) the theta of the apex. 1*1 scalar

%% checking for valid values of apex_theta
if apex_theta>180 || apex_theta<=0
   error('Invalid apex_theta in circle2tri')
end

%% calculating the coordinates of the isosceles triangle
y=radius/tan(apex_theta);
x=radius+radius^2/y;
output=[x -x 0;-radius -radius y];
output=output+coordinates';
end
```